# elasticsearch Nested Query on date

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.4. I need to perform date range query for nested type. And my Mapping is :

```
   "items": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
```

And the sample data for `items` is:

```
"items": [{"value": 53.79585560271698,"date": "2018-10-30 07:30:00"
        },
        {"value": 53.15659716175469,"date": "2018-10-30 07:45:00"
        },
        {"value": 52.13847544211876,"date": "2018-10-30 08:00:00"
        },
        {"value": 51.30296218052354,"date": "2018-10-30 08:15:00"
        },
        {"value": 50.9705640874663,"date": "2018-10-30 08:30:00"
        },
        {"value": 51.37812337892956,"date": "2018-10-30 08:45:00"
        },
        {"value": 51.162125032933545,"date": "2018-10-30 09:00:00"
        }................etc]
```

I used the query :

```
    {  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "objectId":2078
               }
            },
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"items",
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "range":{  
                                 "items.date":{  
                                    "gte":"2018-10-30 07:30:00",
                                    "lte":"2018-10-30 08:30:00"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But the result not filtering with date range that i given.i searched for this query , but solutions not working for me.
I'm new to ES. please give me solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your data actually matches the filter? From snippet you've provided, only 1 document should be in results.

Comment: Could you share the complete mapping details of the index? Alternatively just to test you can remove the `{ "match" : { "objectId": 2078}}` and see if the nested query alone works (It works for me but my mapping didn't had `objectid` field).

Comment: {"dynamic_threshold_values": {"mappings": {"dynamicvalues": {"properties": {"endtDate": {"type": "date","format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},"items": {"type": "nested","properties": {"date": {"type": "date","format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},"value": {"type": "long"}}},"objectId": {"type": "long"},"startDate": {"type": "date","format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},"type": {"type": "keyword"}}}}}}

Comment: @MelvinMoses I created a sample index with the data that you've and the query you've mentioned works correctly. I only see the first `4 documents` what you've mentioned as my query response. Could you reindex the data and give it a try? Do keep an eye after documents are ingested(in logs or kibana) to see if there are any failed docs.

Comment: @Kamal I wonder  on it. i'm using ES 6.4.2 . But the result for my query is entire item.

Comment: @MelvinMoses Of course. So what the query does is it would pull all the documents which has the `items.date` that qualify as per the range query. And the response would return the *entire document*. And if you would like to filter only certain items in that items collection on top of the query result, then I'm afraid it needs to be done on client side.

Comment: thanks Kamal  for ur valuable time. and one more question is there any way to implement scale in the above query(i mean date_histogram->interval)?

Comment: @MelvinMoses Apologies for delay. What do you mean by scale here, do you mean to limit the results?